# Way to get Venue capacity from Google API

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-search, google-knowledge-graph

Is there a Google API that provides a capacity of a particular place or venue.
Let's say Bank of America stadium.
If we do a search with the name on Google then at right hand side of the page, we see the detailed information which also contains the capacity of that particular place.
Is there any API to achieve this particular state.

Knowledge Search API of Google provides some of the details but not the capacity of that venue.

Comment: May possible only for stadium

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same

Comment: Has anyone found a way to do this?